# Why is my dataweave map code not working?

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to convert some code from mule 3 to mule 4 so I'm using dataweave 2. I keep getting errors from this code

```
keySets: if(payload.autoQuote !=null) payload.autoQuote map (autoQuote) -> {
    (if(payload.autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles != null) autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles map ((vehicles,indexOfvehicle) ->{
        keySet: {
            key: if(vehicles.usage != null) vehicles.usage else 'DNF' ,
            keySequence: "TAUTO_USE_TYPE" ++ '_' ++ indexOfvehicle
    }
    } else {}))
} else {}
```

On the first line I'm getting
mismatched input '->' expecting 'else'

on the second line I'm getting
- missing EOF at 'payload'

and
- no viable alternative at input '('
on the first two '('

Answer (score 0):

I believe keySets is a list and not a object, you should be using [] and not {} in your else statements.  I edited some of the braces, and it is compiling fine for me, though not sure if it will work as expected for you.

```
keySets: if(payload.autoQuote !=null) (payload.autoQuote map (autoQuote) -> {
    (if(payload.autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles != null) 
        autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles map ((vehicles,indexOfvehicle) -> {
            keySet: {
                key: if(vehicles.usage != null) vehicles.usage else 'DNF',
                keySequence: "TAUTO_USE_TYPE" ++ '_' ++ indexOfvehicle
        }
    }) else [])
}) else []
```

Give it a try and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't give me errors, though I'm not sure if it makes sense:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    keySets: if(payload.autoQuote !=null) (payload.autoQuote) map(autoQuote, i)  -> {
        ( if(payload.autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles != null) (autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles) map (vehicles,indexOfvehicle) ->{
            keySet: {
                key: if(vehicles.usage != null) vehicles.usage else 'DNF' ,
                keySequence: "TAUTO_USE_TYPE" ++ '_' ++ indexOfvehicle
            }
        } else {})
    } else {}
}
```

You should give an example of the input and the expected output.

Also I'm not sure why you don't use the autoQuoteparameter of the map inside of the map instead of payload.autoQuote...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the parentheses wrong. The first else was in the parentheeses after the map. It should look like this. Don't know if it works but it at least compiles.

```
keySets: if(payload.autoQuote !=null) payload.autoQuote map (autoQuote) -> {
    (if(payload.autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles != null) autoQuote.personalAuto.vehicles map ((vehicles,indexOfvehicle) ->{
    keySet: {
        key: if(vehicles.usage != null) vehicles.usage else 'DNF' ,
        keySequence: "TAUTO_USE_TYPE" ++ '_' ++ indexOfvehicle
}
}) else {})
} else {}
```